# php Fatal error: Call to undefined method TCPDF::addTTFfont() in

Tags: php, pdf, tcpdf

I`m using TCPDF class for making pdf file.

my code :

```
    $pdf = new TCPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false);
$fontname = $pdf->addTTFfont('../common/pdf/fonts/persianFont/HiwebNazanin.ttf', 'TrueTypeUnicode', '', 32);
$pdf->SetFont($fontname, '', 12, '', 'false');
```

I want to change the default font to my font and addTTFfont method has been sugested in TCPDF docs. but I get this error!!

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method TCPDF::addTTFfont() in ...

why I cant use it?!!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

In TCPDF (Version 6.2.6) working with:

```
require_once('/your_path_to/tcpdf.php');
$pdf = new TCPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false);
$fontname = TCPDF_FONTS::addTTFfont('../common/pdf/fonts/persianFont/HiwebNazanin.ttf', 'TrueTypeUnicode', '', 32);
```

Comment: PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined method TCPDF::AddTTFfont()

Comment: How to add Yekan font to TCPDF? Do you any version of Yekan font that fits good with TCPDF?

Answer (score 0):

You can access to http://fonts.snm-portal.com/ in order to convert .ttf or .otf file to some files TCPDF can read.
Then download 3 files:  font_name.z,arial.ctg.z,arial.php and move to /tcpdf/fonts folder.
Then you can use "font_name" in $pdf->SetFont function.